# Angular mat-date-range-input custom dateInput

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-datetimepicker

I have created a demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8bvyfh?file=src/app/app.module.ts

I created `mat-date-range-input`, which works with `MomentDateAdapter`. When I select days from different months all fine:
[image]

But if I select days from the same month, it's expected, that month will be omitted. So instead of:
[image]

I would like to see: "24 - 27 October". How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo in this [Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ozqqct?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

One work around is you can replace text from input using template reference variable.

```
  <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker">
   <input
     #dateRangeStart
      matStartDate
      placeholder="Start date"
      (blur)="dateRangeChange(dateRangeStart, dateRangeEnd)"
      (dateChange)="dateRangeChange(dateRangeStart, dateRangeEnd)"
    />
    <input
      matEndDate
      placeholder="End date"
      #dateRangeEnd
      (dateChange)="dateRangeChange(dateRangeStart, dateRangeEnd)"
    />
  />
```

and then inside component.ts file you can do like this

```
  dateRangeChange(s, e) {
    s.value = s.value.split(' ')[0];
  }
```